# Mysqld reserving more and more memory over time (query cache disabled)

Tags: mysql, performance, memory, mariadb

After a few weeks running, mysqld (mariadb) is reserving more and more memory as you can see on the screenshot below

[htop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCKbq.png)

Some answers says that disabling query caching will help, so i did add to /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
```

and tried to restart mysqld but the reserved memory is still the same after the restart.
I didn't touch anything else on the my.conf and using both myisam and innodb tables

Also `RESET QUERY CACHE` on selected db does nothing at all

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, and 209MB of RAM is very small for a typical MySQL deployment. Did you change any settings away from defaults? That memory consumption looks about right if you haven't. How big is your data?

Comment: I didn't change the config except for the query_cache settings. My db size is 170mb. 209 mb reserved is small but x 40, it takes almost all the memory available. I need the memory for others applications..

Comment: It's not x40. Look with regular `top`.

Answer (score 1):

Some things that are allocated in RAM grow up to some limit, then stick with that setting.  The buffer_pool (cf `innodb_buffer_pool_size`) is the main memory allocation.  When you start mysqld, only a little space is allocated for it.  As you process data, tables are opened, etc, and the buffer_pool grows.  This is *probably* what you are seeing.

The Query cache is generally useless and should be left off.  (There are rare exceptions.)  Even if you use it, it would probably not explain what you are seeing.  It quickly fills up, fragments and remains (I think) stuck at `query_cache_size`.

If you need the memory for other apps, then *do* decrease `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  With only 170MB of data (including indexes?), a setting of 250M is probably more than adequate.  Possibly 100M would work OK, but I would not go that low without adequate need for the RAM elsewhere.

The buffer_pool is used for a variety of things, but it is a "cache".  That is, to handle all your data, it needs to be more then 170M, but being a cache, it is find to set it less than that.  (But understand that may lead to more I/O.)

The Htop shows that not all of your 8GB of RAM is in use.

Also, lower `max_connections`; this will decrease the per-connection memory allocations.  For *most* users `20` is sufficient.  (Then watch for error messages something like 'cannot get a connection'.)